# Parsing shift-reduce conflict

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, reduce, shift, cup

I am using JavaCUP tool in order to produce a parser for my language. I am trying to write a grammar that matches nested and multiple if_else statements.

**Input file**

```
// matches 
if () 
    if ()

    else

    if ()

    else
else

// no match -> modifying grammar leads to shift/reduce conflict
if ()

else
```

**Grammar**

```
expr ::=  if_then_else_statement;

if_then_else_statement ::= IF LPAREN RPAREN if_then_else_statement ELSE if_then_else_statement
                        | ;
```

This grammar matches nested if_else statements. However it only recognizes the first nested if_else statement of my input file.

I modified my grammar in order to match multiple statements like this:

```
expr ::=  expr if_then_else_statement;
      | ;

if_then_else_statement ::= IF LPAREN RPAREN if_then_else_statement ELSE if_then_else_statement
                        | ;
```

The result was a shift/reduce conflict caused by the empty rule (I guess). How can I modify it to support both nested and multiple if_else statements without the use of precedence?

Comment: Do you have a rule which matches multiple statements?

Comment: Yes, after modifying it, expr could reduce to expr if_then_else_statement which could reduce to expr if_then_else_statement if_then_else_statement and finally to if_then_else_statement if_then_else_statement. But this works only in theory

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution would be something like this:

```
expr_list ::= | expr_list expr ;
expr ::= if_then_else_statement ;
if_then_else_statement ::= IF LPAREN RPAREN expr ELSE expr ;
```

That doesn't allow empty `else` clauses (or empty `then` clauses) because an empty else clause is ambiguous: there is no way to tell whether the `s2` in `if () s1 else s2` is the else clause or a statement which follows a complete if statement with an empty else clause.

To resolve that ambiguity, you need statement terminators (eg. semicolon) or `if` statement terminators (`fi` and `end` are common choices) or something else.

Comment: This doesn't work either .Warning : *** Shift/Reduce conflict found in state #10
  between if_then_else_statement ::= IF LPAREN RPAREN expr_list ELSE expr_list (*) 
  and     if_then_else_statement ::= (*) IF LPAREN RPAREN expr_list ELSE expr_list 
  under symbol IF
  Resolved in favor of shifting.

Comment: Replaced the stupid unworkable answer with an explanation of the ambiguity. Ambiguous grammars are hard to parse unless your computer has a mind-reading interface, which you s still have uncommon. Good luck. I'm afk until next week, probably.